# HTML Razor if statements not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2013

I am working in a cshtml file using Razor syntax to create a calendar for a given month using a table. I have the following snippet of code as part of it:

```
@for(int i = 1; i < ViewBag.numdays; i++)
{
    if(true)
    {
        <td>@i</td>
    }

    if(ViewBag.col == 6)
    {
        </tr><tr>
    }

    if(ViewBag.col == 6)
    {
        ViewBag.col = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.col++;
    }
}
```

(Note I've checked while debugging that the two ViewBag variables have valid int values and they work elsewhere in the program)

This code builds without any errors. However when I actually run it, it crashes in the browser. It sites the line containing the for statement as where the error occurred and says *The for block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.* I also noticed that in Visual Studio, where it usually will highlight the closing bracket when the cursor is next to the opening bracket, it does not do that for the loop. In addition it also does not do it for any of the if statements inside except the first (I don't mean highlighting the wrong bracket, it just doesn't highlight anything). I'm really stuck as to what I'm doing wrong with the syntax here, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I just realized the `if(true)` may look odd, at first I thought perhaps just creating the line of HTML within it then using if statements was the problem, so that was just an attempt to fix it, to no avail.

Comment: I believe you may need the @ in front of your viewbag references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, it's the line

```
</tr><tr>
```

That is throwing it off - possibly because it isn't valid html. Try replacing that line with

```
@:</tr><tr>
```

and it should work fine.  However, your code is also producing an error for me on the line:

```
ViewBag.col++;
```

I believe you will have to create a local variable in the razor to handle the column, because you can't increment on a dynamic variable in the ViewBag.

Comment: That was it, thank you! (EDIT) Regarding that second part though, that portion is actually working for me, I do have <code>ViewBag.col</code> initialized before this snippet to an integer (between 0 and 6), this may fix it for you too

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because ASP.NET's Razor engine won't let you split up your HTML tags like that. Each "block" has to contain well-formed HTML. Thus, this is your problem section because you've opened a `<tr>` but didn't close it in that block:

```
if(ViewBag.col == 6)
{
    </tr><tr>
}
```

You'll need to think of a completely different approach. I would try first figuring out the [number of weeks in the month](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ec3fde61-03d9-4609-ba02-d836a8073630/number-of-weeks-in-month?forum=vblanguage). Loop through those, opening your `<tr>` at the beginning and closing it at the end. Hopefully that's enough for you to get started (sorry, a bit too busy at the moment to give you something more complete).

```
@for (int i = 0; i < weeksInMonth; i++)
{
    <tr>
        @* do stuff here *@
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize I am a bit late to the party here but I wanted to leave a complete answer to the question.  Please be gentle as this is my very first post on this site. Of course constructive criticism is welcomed.

I was having the same problem with unmatched braces while building a calendar.

The key here is as 'howcheng' mentioned:  ASP.NET's Razor engine won't let you split up your HTML tags like that. Each "block" has to contain well-formed HTML. The solution for the problem is to use: @: as 'john' has pointed out.  ScottGu's blog says:

Using @: to explicitly indicate the start of content

Not all content container blocks start with a tag element tag, though, and there are scenarios where the Razor parser can’t implicitly detect a content block.

Razor addresses this by enabling you to explicitly indicate the beginning of a line of content by using the @: character sequence within a code block.  The @: sequence indicates that the line of content that follows should be treated as a content block.

Here is my solution to the problem.  It is not complete because it needs clean-up but it does work.  I did not count the number of weeks but looped through the days:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <table class='calendar'>
        <tr><td class='calMthName' colspan='7'>  @Model.MonthName, @Model.Year </td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th class='calDOW'>Sunday</th>
            <th class='calDOW'>Monday</th>
            <th class='calDOW'>Tuesday</th>
            <th class='calDOW'>Wednesday</th>
            <th class='calDOW'>Thursday</th>
            <th class='calDOW'>Friday</th>
            <th class='calDOW'>Saturday</th>
        </tr> 
        @for (DateTime today = Model.BegDate; today <= Model.EndDate; today = today.AddDays(1))
        {
            var dow = today.DayOfWeek;
            Int32 nbrDow = Convert.ToInt32(today.DayOfWeek.ToString("d"));            
            if (dow == DayOfWeek.Sunday || today == Model.BegDate)
            {
                @:<tr class='calRow'>
            }
            if (today == Model.BegDate && nbrDow != 0)
            {
                for (Int32 idx = 0; idx < nbrDow; idx++)
                {
                    <td class='calNonDay'> </td>
                }
            }
            String style = today == Model.SelectedDate ? "calDaySelected" : "";
            <td class='calDay @style'>
                <div class='calDayTitle'>  @today.Day.ToString()  </div>              
            </td>
            if (today == Model.EndDate && nbrDow != 6)
            {
                for (Int32 idx = nbrDow; idx < 6; idx++)
                {
                    <td class='calNonDay'> </td>
                }
            }
            if (dow == DayOfWeek.Saturday || today == Model.EndDate)
            {
                @:</tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
}
```